# Simple 3 lines Trigger Test

Tags: trigger, deployment

Below trigger is working successfully in single Account Standard Object. But I need to test the trigger for deployment from Sandbox to Production.

```
trigger ExecutiveOwner on Account(before insert, before update){
    Account Owner = [Select Executive_Owner__c from Account 
                      Where Account.Strategic__c= null or Account.Strategic__c= 'No' 
                      limit 1];
    Owner.Executive_Owner__c = null;
}
```

Below is fields Info on Account:

- Strategic__c
- Executive_Owner__c

Comment: This trigger doesn't *do* anything. At all. Except possibly crash when no accounts match the criteria.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.
Trigger working fine.
But it is deployment time.
I'm new to apex, i'm unable to wright a trigger.
Please sort out. Thanks,
Manu

Comment: What are you trying to do with this trigger.  Please add more detail.

Comment: @ManoharReddy - The trigger is useless. You are basically attempting to set a field value to null on insert or update. So why have that field in the first place. Are you sure that you are accomplishing your goal? In addition, what if multiple accounts are inserted or updated, trigger will not work. As for the test class, what have you tried so far. Since detail seems to not be your concern, simple do `Account a = New Account(Name='test'); insert account` and you will have it covered

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking a shot in the dark for what you're trying to accomplish but how about this instead. It's setting the executive owner to null if the account isn't strategic:

```
for (Account thisAcct : trigger.new) {
   if ( thisAcct.Account.Strategic__c==null || thisAcct.Strategic__c=='No') {
       thisAcct.executive_owner__c = null;
   }
}
```

If this is what you're trying to accomplish you might want to look into if a trigger is really your best solution. Perhaps a validation rule?